# XCeed WPF Toolkit -use Controls on Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have problems to use the Extended WPF Toolkit controls in the XAML designer
environmet: Win8.1, WPF Toolkit 2.1.0.0, MS VisualStudio Express 2013
What have I done?
- Downlod the actual "Extended WPF Toolkit Binaries" from Codeplex-Homepage, unzip....
- include the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit in my project - referencies    ( o.k )
- in Toolbox: Add a new Tab "WPF Toolkit Extended"    ( o.k )
- in the new registercard: Add Items. I see all the about 70 customs controls (ex. SingleUpDown and so on)  (o.k)
- I try to drag and drop a custom (ex. SingleUpDown) to my main window.   DOESN'T WORK

I get a messagebox (in german, I try to translate)
" a reference "XCeed.WPF.Toolkit, Version 2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4" was added to the project. Press OK to restart the XAML Designer, that you can use the new types / controls out of the new referencies. After restart of the XAML designer you should do it again.

When I restart the Designer, or VisualStudio or even the computer, its always the same message. And I do not see the reference to the toolkit in the XAML designer.

I surely also tried all the referencies and hints on the codeplex installation site:

Add a using statement ("using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;") to the top of .cs files
Add a new xmlns (for example, xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit") to the top of XAML files
In your XAML, use the namespace prefix (in the above example, )

But this also doesn't work.

Is  there any idea, why I am not able to drag and drop the controls to my main window and what is wrong in my approach. (I am pretty new to C# and WPF)

SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY SORRY

I just solved it by additional google search. problem is to unblock properties after DLL-Downloads. My salvation was this comment:

This is a common problem when downloading files from thw web.  Simply go to the folder where you downloaded the DLL.  Right-click the DLL and select properties.  Near the bottom of the properties dialog there should be a button that says "Unblock".  Click that and you should be good to go.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to add the WPF toolkit via Nuget.

If you don't have nuget already installed, go to Tools -> Extension and Updates in Visual studio. On the online section you should find Nuget easily it always appear on top, then click "download"

[image: nuget]

Once Nuget installed, right click on your project in the solution viewer and click on "Manage NuGet packages"

[image: Xceed]

In the menu search for the Wpf Toolkit, and click on "install"

This way you are sure that the library is added correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I thouht NuGet is not for VS Express